# React Native (Android) - Load custom multiple JS bundle on demand

Tags: java, android, react-native

I want a SuperApp-like behaviour where I can load multiple MiniApp bundled separately from another repo.
I've decided this way is the most basic approach without using any additional tools.

A default js bundle typically ouputted to `main.jsbundle`.
So now I have already bundled another 3 apps & output to `android/app/src/main/assets/`:

- `index.miniapp1.android.jsbundle`
- `index.miniapp2.android.jsbundle`
- `index.miniapp3.android.jsbundle`

My bundling command is :
`npx react-native bundle --minify --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output ../mainapp/android/app/src/main/assets/index.miniapp1.android.jsbundle --assets-dest ../mainapp/android/app/src/main/res/`

Then, this is my Java bridge to load the bundle :

```
...

public class ConnectNativeModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {
    ...

    @ReactMethod
    public void openApp(String bundleName, String appPath, ReadableMap initProps) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(reactContext, AppModulesActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("bundleName", bundleName);
        bundle.putString("appPath", appPath);
        bundle.putBundle("initProps", Arguments.toBundle(initProps));
        intent.putExtras(bundle);
        reactContext.startActivity(intent);
        addBridge(bundleName);
    }

    ...
}
```

In react native component, to trigger the bundle load :

```
    const {ConnectNativeModule} = NativeModules ?? {};
    const bundleName = 'miniapp1';
    ConnectNativeModule?.openApp(
        bundleName,
        `index.${bundleName}.android.jsbundle`,
        {
            bundleName,
            actionPage: 'Activity',
        },
    );
```

I've managed to achieve this in iOS with Objective-C bridge with no issue, however in android :

- if using bare react-native package only, it **WORKS** !
  *(without additional package, only the built-in shipped library)*
- if got any library, it crashed with this kind of message depending on what library I've included for the mini apps :
  `E/ReactNativeJS: Invariant Violation: TurboModuleRegistry.getEnforcing(...): 'RNGestureHandlerModule' could not be found. Verify that a module by this name is registered in the native binary., js engine: hermes`
  *(eg: react-navigation)*

In the main app's package.json, I've installed all the packages used in every mini apps with the exact same version. 
I'm also using `yarn workspaces` with `nohoist`

Comment: What is the question? Consider using https://codereview.stackexchange.com if you just want your code to be reviewed.